# Adding column by substring from another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with one column,

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'files': ["S18-000344PAS", "S18-001850HE1", "S18-00344HE1"]})
```

I want to add another column with the substring of files, the final dataframe should look like

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'files': ["S18-000344PAS", "S18-001850HE1", "S18-00344HE1"], 'stain': ["PAS", "HE1", "HE1"]})
```

I try

```
DF["Stain"] = DF.apply(lambda row: row.files[re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]{2,}', row.files).start():], axis=1)
```

But it returned

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract last 3 characters from the `files` column you can do:

```py
DF["stain"] = DF["files"].str[-3:]
print(DF)
```

Prints:

```
           files stain
0  S18-000344PAS   PAS
1  S18-001850HE1   HE1
2   S18-00344HE1   HE1
```

---

EDIT: Using regular expression to extract the `stain`:

```py
DF["stain"] = DF["files"].str.extract(r"^(?:.{2,})-\d*(.+)")
print(DF)
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there a method that can also extract string longer than 3 character?

Comment: @pill45 What is the condition by which should the `stain` string be obtained?

Comment: It will start with alphabet (>=2) and may or may not follow by numbers (of any length).

Comment: @pill45 See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using the `str` accessor

```
DF[["files", "stain"]] = DF["files"].str.extract(pat="(.+\d)(\D.+)")
```

```
    files   stain
0   S18-000344  PAS
1   S18-001850  HE1
2   S18-00344   HE1
```

If you need to keep the extracted variable in the first column, you can do

```
DF["stain"] = DF["files"].str.extract(pat="(.+\d)(\D.+)")[1]
```

```
    files   stain
0   S18-000344PAS   PAS
1   S18-001850HE1   HE1
2   S18-00344HE1    HE1
```